# How do i set reducer output name in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, outputformat

I have a job that will emit 900,000 different outputs. each one of those have to be identified by a specific unique name... that is the "name" I have on the mapOutputKey. How do i do this in map-reduce?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MultipleOutputs`, in the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) you will find example that does almost exactly what you need, you just need to replace the `generateFileName` function to this one:

```
String generateFileName(K k, V v) {
  return k.toString();
}
```